# uniqueConstraint for two colums (not combined)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My model has following annotation

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email", "user_name" }) )
```

My problem is, that this just throws an exception, when the combination of these columns are already taken, but I want an exception when even just one field is already in db. How could I manage this?

Comment: Not sure if hibernate uses JPA syntax, but maybe something like `@Table(uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email"}),
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_name"})
})`?

Comment: Worked! Thank you.